# Strings visually identical but not matching; list iterator exception

Tags: java

I'm new here, so I'm not sure if it's ok to have 2 questions in the same post, so if I'm not supposed to just tell me (nicely!) and I'll change it to one question here and start another post elsewhere.

First problem:

Below on lines 5-8 I'm referring to two strings that I need to compare to see if they are the same. I'm using the `getUserInput()` method to get a response from the user at terminal and then I'm having it go ahead and print both strings so that I can visually inspect them, and they are coming up the same. However, the `if` section that is supposed to run when they are the same never runs and then the `else` section always does.

Second problem:

In the `else` section right below, whenever the `currentChump`'s health is reduced to `< 1`, I get a block of exceptions that I've never seen before and don't know what do do about.

Here is my code, and then below I will paste the exception:

```
for (Chump currentChump : chumpArray) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    String playerChoice = helper.getUserInput(
                          "Type the name of the Weapon that you wish to use.");
    System.out.println(playerChoice);
    System.out.println(currentChump.getWeakness().toLowerCase());
    if (currentChump.getWeakness().toLowerCase() == playerChoice) {
        chumpArray.remove(currentChump);
    } // END IF
    else {
        while (PlayerIsAlive && currentChump.getHealth() > 0) {
            int damage = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            System.out.println(currentChump.getName() + " has "
                             + currentChump.getHealth() + "health remaining.");
            currentChump.setHealth(currentChump.getHealth() - damage);
            System.out.println("You hit the enemy for " 
                             + damage + " points of damage.");
            System.out.println(currentChump.getName() + " has " 
                             + currentChump.getHealth() + " health remaining.");
    System.out.println(" ");
            if (currentChump.getHealth() < 1) {
                chumpArray.remove(currentChump);
            } // END IF
            else {
                int damage2 = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
                player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - damage2);
                if (player.getHealth() < 1) {
                    PlayerIsAlive = false;
                } // END IF
            } // END WHILE
        } // END ELSE
    } // END ELSE
} // END FOR
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
at ArenaGameCopy.startPlaying(ArenaGameCopy.java:87)
at ArenaGameCopy.main(ArenaGameCopy.java:168)
```

Comment: I'm so happy someone thinks I'm great. :)

Comment: In general, you should [ask separate questions separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/193053).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I will do so in the future.

Comment: I tried using the Iterator but I'm getting the same exception.  Edited the OP, added the new code.  Didn't put the exception because it is exactly the same.

Comment: So I tried to edit the OP but it's saying that it can't find the page...  It that because Lee Taylor edited my title?

Comment: Anyway, i just replaced:

for (Chump currentChump : chumpArray)

With:

for (Iterator<Chump> currentChump = chumpArray.iterator(); chumpArray.hasNext();)

And replaced:

chumpArray.remove(currentChump);

with:

currentChump.remove();

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), I will help you out as a Sunday takeaway :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `Iterator` to loop into, when you want to remove items from a List and use [Iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) instead of modifying the list underlying.

Quoting [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> ...it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection
>   while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of
>   the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator
>   implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection
>   implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this
>   exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are
>   known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather
>   that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined
>   time in the future.
>
> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, **if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.**
>
> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for
>   its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only
>   to detect bugs.

---

Let me help you. Read the comments in the code:

```
import java.util.*;

/**
  Hello! Welcome to basics.
  This is what called a SSCCE.
  Next time anyone asks for it, do it.
  Because, 90% of the times, creating SSCCE will help you identify the issue.
  Hope you learn something from these lines.

  To compile and execute this code do the following:
  a. Paste this class from import to last closed bracket in a 
     file named Test.java
  b. javac Test.java
  c. java Test
  Bliss!
*/
public class Test{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    // 1. Do not worry about these lines
    //    I am just creating some sample data
    List<String> chumpArray = Arrays.asList("Oh my god! You must know to create SSCCE".split("\\s"));
    chumpArray = new ArrayList<String>(chumpArray);
    System.out.println("List to be iterated: " + chumpArray);

    // 2. This is what I meant when I said to use an Iterator
    //    Obviously, your iterator will look like Iterator<Chump>
    for(Iterator<String> chumpIt = chumpArray.iterator(); chumpIt.hasNext();) {

        // 3. Materialize the current item
        String currentChump = chumpIt.next();
        System.out.println("Currently on: " + currentChump);

        // 3. String comparison
        //    ==            WRONG
        //    .equals       RIGHT
        if (currentChump.toLowerCase().equals("you")) {
          System.out.println("DELETING: " + currentChump);
          // 4. Just ask the iterator to remove the current Item
          chumpIt.remove();
          // Was it really so hard?!
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List after delete: " + chumpArray);
  }
}
```

On executing this, we get

```
tmp$ java Test
List to be iterated: [Oh, my, god!, You, must, know, to, create, SSCCE]
Currently on: Oh
Currently on: my
Currently on: god!
Currently on: You
DELETING: You
Currently on: must
Currently on: know
Currently on: to
Currently on: create
Currently on: SSCCE
List after delete: [Oh, my, god!, must, know, to, create, SSCCE]
```

HTH
Nishant

Comment: Would anyone be so kind as to teach me how to use Iterator to rework that code?  I've never used it before and and I've been looking at it for awhile now and I don't really understand it. I sure would have a new tool in my tool bag afterwords! Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), I will help you out as a Sunday takeaway :)

Comment: Thanks, Nishant.  Now I'm going to get to work figuring out what that is!

Comment: Wow, that was really great of you to do that! I tried to spend some time on the SSCCE yesterday while i was at work but I got really super busy and wasn't able to get back to coding until now.  Thanks so much for the help, and in the future I will provide SSCCE, hopefully figuring out my issues on my own in the process.

Comment: Ok, so now I have another issue :(  
Now i've replace the enhanced for loop with the iterator, using the same name (currentChump) for the thing in the array being looked at by the loop.  The compiler is complaining now whenever I try to call one of that objects's methods. (It says "cannot find symbol")

Comment: that's either an import issue or a classpath issue. Try using an IDE like Eclipse, it will help you to solve this. If it does not work, create a new question. Remember, one question per post.

Comment: Got it, I'll try that, and then failing that, I'll do a new post with one question, in the form of SSCCE!

Comment: Nope, nope, turned out that just following your instructions better solved the problem.  I started to make a  SSCCE and I was able to solve my own problem.You are the man Nishant.  I'm super serious man, let me know if there's anything I can ever do for you.

Answer (score 7):

You cant use == to compare strings as == will compare the objects ... not the value of the strings

`if (currentChump.getWeakness().toLowerCase() == playerChoice)`

should be

```
if (currentChump.getWeakness().toLowerCase().equals(playerChoice))
```

or

```
 if (currentChump.getWeakness().equalsIgnoreCase(playerChoice))
```

2nd issue seems that you are trying to modify an object (your list) that is part of another thread.

Comment: 2nd issue is wrong. It's not multi-threading at all. It's removing an item from a List while iterating over it. The `(Chump currentChump : chumpArray)` statement creates an `Iterator` under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

**First problem**

Always use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) when comparing Strings !

What the `==` operator does is check if the objects are one and the same.

The only reason this seems to work with Strings is because of something called [interning](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/).

This means that, unless the String constructor has been explicitly used, references with the same character sequence point to the same String object. This is to supposedly to reduce memory usage.

**Second problem**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

This is caused by modifying the structure you're iterating through using the enhanced for loop.

This [link](http://javaadami.blogspot.be/2007/09/enhanced-for-loop-and.html) explains why the Exception is thrown.

> In each next() method call of the iterator,
>
> ```
>   final void checkForComodification() {
>       if (modCount != expectedModCount)
>     throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
>   }
> ```
>
> method is called, to check if there is a chance is made in the list.
>   This throws the ConcurrentModificationException in case they do not
>   match.

**Additional comments**

For the sake of conventions which you seem to have partly respected you could rename your boolean variable from `PlayerIsAlive` to `isPlayerAlive`. This is in camelCase with a first minuscule and a "is" to immediately indicate to the reader that it's a true/false value.